# ViewStub inflation of ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-viewbinding, viewstub

I want to leverage [ViewStub](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/loading-ondemand#Load) to optionally show a portion of UI. When the root of my inflated item is [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout) then it doesn't render.
[image: ConstraintLayout]

But if that root is [MaterialCardView](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/card/MaterialCardView) then it displays as intended.
[image: MaterialCardView]

```xml
<!-- my_fragment.xml -->

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentRootLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ViewStub
        android:id="@+id/fragmentViewStub"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inflatedId="@+id/fragmentViewStub"
        android:layout="@layout/item"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

```xml
<!-- item.xml -->

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/itemRootLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
        android:id="@+id/itemLabel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/itemLabelText"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

```kotlin
/* MyFragment.kt */

@AndroidEntryPoint
class MyFragment : Fragment(R.layout.my_fragment) {
    private val viewModel: MyViewModel by viewModels()

    private val viewBinding: MyFragmentBinding by viewLifecycleLazy {
        MyFragmentBinding.bind(requireView())
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        viewBinding.fragmentViewStub.inflate()
    }
}
```

I've tried [matching the ViewStub's `id`/`inflatedId` attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47164398/how-to-use-viewstub-in-constraintlayout) and [programmatically setting dimensions/constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50747930/constraintlayout-setting-constraintheight-default-programmatically) but neither solved the issue.

What am I overlooking about making these pieces work together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to update with my answer/oversight. This worked as expected in both cases all along.

Nightmode was enabled and the behavior of `MaterialCardView` has automatic contrast between its card and content. Meanwhile, when `ConstraintLayout` inverts its theme the label *appears* to be missing but is indeed present, as white text on white background.